# Quick search by name not return products but advanced search by name returns products

Tags: magento-1.9, search, advanced-search, search-type

I have major issue, when i try to type products name in quick search its return no products, same name typed by advanced search its good, also return products.

> Note : visibility - catalog,search; qty - enough qty; proper cached
>   and reindex,still not working. am not using third party search
>   extension, using still default magento extension.

Answer (score 0):

Login `adminpanel`

go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`

Search `name` in `attribute_code` and click on the row

in `Frontend Properties` set `Use in Quick Search` to `yes`

then do `reindex` clear cache and check

also check your product `visibility` it should be `catalog,search`

Comment: @ Murtuza Zabuawala : i did already but no use

Comment: @Aveeva check my last added line

Comment: @ Murtuza Zabuawala : Actually my all products visibility is catalog,search.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by attribute properties.

1. Login to admin panel
2. open your attribute by catalog > attributes > manage attributes,
3. Find your attribute by typing your attribute's code or Label.
4. Open attribute and check the Frontend properties for Quick search and Advanced search inside of your attribute.

   [image]
5. After modified the attribute, you need to clear cache and re-index the data.

Comment: @ Teja bhagavan Kollepara : I did already, but no use,